# 2 errors in libsvm matlab "Model does not support probabiliy estimates and Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch"

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm, libsvm, supervised-learning

I want to classify a list of 5 test images using the library LIBSVM with a strategy 'one against all' in order to obtain probabilities for each class. the used code is bellow :

```
load('D:\xapp.mat');
load('D:\xtest.mat');
load('D:\yapp.mat');%% matrix contains true class of images yapp=[641;645;1001;1010;1100]
load('D:\ytest.mat');%% matrix contains unlabeled class of test set  ytest=[1;2;3;4;5]
numLabels=max(yapp);
numTest=size(ytest,1);
%# train one-against-all models
model = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
   model{k} = svmtrain(double(yapp==k),xapp, ['-c 1000 -g 10 -b 1 ']);
end
%# get probability estimates of test instances using each model
prob = zeros(numTest,numLabels);
for k=1:numLabels
   [~,~,p] = svmpredict(double(ytest==k), xtest, model{k}, '-b 1');
   prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k
end
%# predict the class with the highest probability
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
acc = sum(pred == ytest) ./ numel(ytest)    %# accuracy
```

I obtain this error :

> Model does not support probabiliy estimates
>   Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>      Error in comp (line 98)
>      prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k

please, help me to solve this error and thanks in advance

Comment: I reckon the error is in line `numLabels=max(yapp);`. In this line you basically say that there are 1100 labels whereas this is incorrect since you have 5 labels. If `yapp=[641;645;1001;1010;1100]`, then the number of classes is `length(yapp)`, not `max(yapp)`.

Comment: thanks for replying, to clarify : xapp represent training set and xtest contain the test set. I know that the proplem comes from this line numLabels=max(yapp); but when I replace max  by length(yapp), I get the same error. thanks for any suggestion

Comment: you should also pay attention to the line `double(yapp==k)`. With `k` that goes from 1 to `numLabels` and `yapp` which is in range `[641;645;1001;1010;1100]`, that equality will never be verified. I don't think this will remove the error, but you'll get all-zero labels for all classes and this will never lead to correct results

Comment: yes, this is the problem exactly. this implementation is for svm one against all in libsvm. please, have any idea for any other implementation to solve this error

Comment: Well, since `yapp` and `ytest` both contain the labels, they should contain the same range of values (i.e. from 1 to 5). If you don't know a priori the labels for the test set, that's not a *real* test set: these are just unclassified patterns and the SVMs will return their estimated label. If `ytest` contents are just dummy numbers from 1 to 5, then you cannot use it for accuracy evaluation and/or performance evaluation (just like you do in a *real* test set). You have to gather the first output from `svmpredict()`, these will be the estimated labels.

Comment: yes, in this case , I don't have any idea for the label in test set. but how svm will return their estimated label??? can you explain more. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to use a code snippet that evaluates a SVM classifier performances whereas your goal is to properly estimate the labels for your test set.

I assume your five labels are `[641;645;1001;1010;1100]` (as in `yapp`). First thing you have to do is delete `ytest`, because you don't know any labels for the test set. It is pointless to fill `ytest` with some dummy values: the SVMs will return our predicted labels.

The first error, as already pointed out in the comments is in

```
numLabels=max(yapp);
```

you must change `max()` with `length()` in order to gather the number of classes.

The training stage is almost correct.
Given the fact that `k` goes from 1 to 5 whereas `yapp` has the range above, you should consider changing `double(yapp==k)` into `double(yapp==yapp(k))`: in this manner we mark as positive the k-th value in `yapp`. Given the fact that `k` goes from 1 to 5, then `yapp(k)` will go from 641 to 1100.

And now the prediction stage.
The first input for `svmpredict()` should be the test labels but now we don't know them so we can fill it with a vector of zeros (there will be as many zeros as there are patterns in the test set). That is because `svmpredict()` automatically returns the accuracy as well if the test labels are known, but that's not the case. So you must change the second for-loop to

```
for k=1:numLabels
   [~,~,p] = svmpredict(zeros(size(xtest,1),1), xtest, model{k}, '-b 1');
   prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k
end
```

and finally predict the labels with

```
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
```

and `pred` contains the predicted labels.

*Note 1*: in this method, however, you cannot measure accuracy and/or other parameters because what we called the test set actually is not a test set. A test set is a labelled set and we pretend we don't know its labels in order to let the SVM predict them and then match the predicted labels with the actual labels in order to measure its accuracy.

*Note 2*: predicted labels in `pred` will most likely have values in range 1 to 5 due to the second for-loop. However, since your labels have different values, you can map back taking into account that 1 is 641, 2 is 645, 3 is 1001, 4 is 1010, 5 is 1100.

Comment: I tried this, but I get a matrix pred as fellow pred=[5;5;5;5;5] but in reality the class labels is in [641;645;1001;1010;1100]. what is the problem exactly?